# XSLT: How to match (in template) two different elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have 2 different elements: "edge" and "containedEdge" but for both I need to do the same work with them. I want to use one template for both.

How will template look like for matching "edge or containedEdge"?

XML input:

```
<packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Activity" xmi:id="EAID_AC000001_2A09_4795_BBF6_189BCF2176FD" name="EA_Activity1" visibility="public">
    <edge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="EAID_7178621A_9B6C_4fd5_9E5D_AFB31B6DEF24"/>
    <subgroup xmi:type="uml:LoopNode" xmi:id="EAID_61782877_58D5_41e6_B4BA_3C79CC4ADCFF">
        <containedEdge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="EAID_C43E5114_A121_4a58_948C_3F7865CDDE19"/>
        <containedEdge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="EAID_1300F655_DD16_4303_BD5F_E3180B655DC4"/>
    </subgroup>
    <edge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="EAID_2612A8E5_CBC2_406d_B3F5_255C49DC728F"/>
    <edge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="EAID_7F330DC1_68BA_48e2_BAE2_15DC5BCAC772"/>
</packagedElement>
```

I need use template similar to this but "or" there shouldn´t be I think:

```
<xsl:for-each select="packagedElement/edge or packagedElement/subgroup/containedEdge">
        <element geometry="SX=0;SY=0;EX=0;EY=0;Path=;" subject="EAID_CONNECTR{substring(@xmi:id, 14, 28)}" style=";Hidden=0;"/>   
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a union in the select:

```
<xsl:for-each select="packagedElement/edge|packagedElement/subgroup/containedEdge">
  <element geometry="SX=0;SY=0;EX=0;EY=0;Path=;" subject="EAID_CONNECTR{substring(@xmi:id, 14, 28)}" style=";Hidden=0;"/>   
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: @Roboros - Ahh yes. I see you've added code to your question. The union operator will work in a select too. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#combining_seq Also updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. It works, but I tried it yesterday and it didn´t work. Somewhere was mistake.